# Looking for better way to set resizeable background Css3 / HTML / mootools

Tags: html, css, mootools

I found some code that allows me to resize browser window and reset image h+w appropriately like so

```
    html {
        background: url(css/images/600.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

I'm not clear how to change the background of this element as the following line fails to find the html element

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    $(this).setStyle('background', 'url(css/images/600.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;');
});
```

How can I change the background image of the html tag through mootools script? Would it be better to set a class to the html element , if so how do I reference the element by Class?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using $(this).css();? (instead of setStyle)

Comment: @Mark, `.css();` is a jQuery function, not Mootools.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've never used MooTools

Answer (score 0):

inside the domready function, `this` is the `window` element not the `html` element

should be something like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    this.document.html.setStyle('background', 'url(css/images/600.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
});
```

Hope this helps

**BTW:** i wouldn't give a style to the html element, it causes problems on IE. It's better to style the body tag or create a wrapper div